# What does Convert to Web Application do?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-applications

In VS2008, I go to File/New/Project, select ASP.NET Web Application and create a new project.

If I right-click on the newly created project, there is a menu item to **Convert to Web Application**.

I thought I just picked a Web Application.  What exactly does the **Convert to Web Application** menu item do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will generate .designer file with controls from aspx/ascx file. If you have e.g. in you page control

```
<asp:Label ID="lbId" runat="server" />
```

in designer file it generates member

```
 protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbId;
```

if you haven't this .designer file you cannot use controls from aspx page in code behind.